# Instantaneous eigenstate and time dependent Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, eigenvalue, adiabatic

Instantaneous eigenstate $\psi(t)$ is defined as
$\hat H(t)\psi(t)=E(t)\psi(t)\tag{1}$

But in the lecture notes of Quantum Physics III MIT (in the section of adiabatic approximation), it is written that $\psi(t)$ may not be the solution of time dependent Schrodinger equation.

I am not able to understand why is it that.
At $t=0$, $(1)$ becomes $\hat H(0)\psi(0)=E(0)\psi(0)\tag{2}$
This means $\psi(0)$ is the eigenstate of $\hat H(0)$
We know that TDSE is first order in time. If we know the state at time $t=0$, then we get state vector at other times also.
$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t)=\hat H(t)\psi(t),\;\text{At t=0 we have }\psi(0)\tag{3}$
Now from $(3)$, $\psi(t)$ evolves and $\hat H$ also changes with time as it depends explicitly on time.
So can't $\psi(t)$ will evolve such that $(1)$ and $(3)$ holds simultaneously?
I am not able to clearly understand why both $(1)$ amd $(3)$ won't hold simultaneously.

Comment: Which book? Can you provide a more direct quote?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have edited in my post

Comment: I think I have difficulty in interpreting instantaneous eigenstate.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433851/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-with-a-time-dependent-hamiltonian

Comment: You can type $\hbar$ as `\hbar` in MathJax (LaTeX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point made by Zweibach in those notes is true even for time-independent Hamiltonians.

Let $\psi:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathscr H$ be a trajectory through the Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, where $\psi(t)$ is understood to be the state vector of the system at time $t$.  The Schrodinger equation is
$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = H(t) \psi(t)\tag{1}$$

Let us assume that for each $t$, $\psi(t)$ is an eigenvector of $H(t)$ with eigenvalue $E(t)$.  That is,
$$H (t)\psi(t) = E(t)\psi(t)\tag{2}$$

Zweibach's point is that it does **not** follow that $\psi(t)$ is a solution to $(1)$. Plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields
$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = E(t) \psi(t) \implies \psi'(t) = -\frac{i E(t)}{\hbar} \psi(t)$$

Obviously this equation is not satisfied by arbitrary trajectories $\psi$; even if the Hamiltonian is time-independent and $E(t) \equiv E_0$ is constant, in order for $\psi$ to be a solution to $(1)$ we must have that
$$\psi(t) = e^{-iE_0 t/\hbar} \psi(0)$$

As an explicit example, consider the elementary particle in a box of length $L$.  The ground state eigenvector for this system is $\psi_0 = \sqrt{2/L} \sin\big(\pi x/L\big)$ with eigenvalue $E_0 = \pi^2\hbar^2/2mL^2$.   If we let $\psi(t)=\psi_0$, we see that for each $t$, $\psi(t)$ is an instantaneous eigenvector of the Hamiltonian (meaning that $H\psi(t) = E_0 \psi(t)$); however, it is also obvious that $\psi(t)$ does not solve the (time-dependent) Schrodinger equation $(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to see this is with an example. Consider a Hamiltonian that changes suddenly at $t=0$
\begin{align}
H(t) = \begin{cases} H_1 & t \le 0 \\ H_2 & t > 0  \end{cases}
\end{align}
Now the instantaneous eigenstates will, correspondingly, change suddenly at $t=0$ from eigenstates of $H_1$ to eigenstates of $H_2$. If we consider the solutions to the Scrhodinger equation, however, there is no way they can jump in this way. They do not know what Hamiltonian $H_2$ the system is going to jump to, or that it going to jump at all.

The *instantaneous* eigenstates are just that; they are entirely determined by the *instantaneous* Hamiltonian. The result of *integrating* the Schrodinger equation, however it determined by the entire history of $H(t)$ for all times back to whatever time we set our boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have one follow up doubt. Consider a general case. Like at t=0, $\hat H(0)$ has a set of eigen vectors. Take any of them say $\psi(0)$. This is the state which the system is in at t=0. Now for any $\epsilon>0$, $\hat H(\epsilon)$ have some other set of eigen states. Now say we take $\tilde\psi(\epsilon)$. Now can we say as $\epsilon\to 0,\;\tilde\psi(\epsilon)\to\psi(0)$? Because if that is the case, then we can see $\psi$ to be evolving with time which have to be also the solution of TDSE.

Comment: The example in my answer gives an explicit counterexample. In this case $\tilde{\psi}$ is an eigenstate of $H_2$. As $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ it time evolves trivially under $H_2$ and so does not tend to $\psi(0)$, which is some eigenstate of $H_1$

Comment: Ok I think now I have understood. So, basically the $(1)$ may not be the evolution equation of state vector, as you have shown in your example. But by adiabatic approximation, we can write the evolution of staye vector in terms of instantaneous eigen states. Am I correct?

Comment: And also in your example if we use time dependent perturbation theory upto first order we can get a superposition of eigenstates (of t>0) not a pure state as given in (1). So (1)  is not an evolution equation.

Comment: I just have one last doubt. In your example you have explicitly assumed discontinuity in the Hamiltonian. But suppose the Hamiltonian is varying continuously, the how can we be sure that $(1)$ is not an evolution equation.